# Count Distinct Records While Avoiding Duplicate Rows in SQL Query Output

Tags: sql, count, duplicates, distinct

My SQL query isn't correctly counting Legal Description Parcel Numbers (LDPARC) and it is duplicating accounts (ACCTNO). As you likely know, ACCTNOs can have more than one LDPARCs. So the table LDPARC is in tbl_Loan_Legal_Descriptions is my issue.  When an account has multiple LDPARCs, I need to count the number of Parcel Numbers and simply get the count while grabbing a few other fields with my query while avoiding duplicates when I join it to my "primary" table tbl_loan_master.  Only the first line of my Where clause is relevant to the count.  I know you can't use DISTINCT with COUNT when also using PARTITION, so that may be part of the solution.  I would greatly appreciate any help.  Here is a slimmed down version of my query:

```
With CTE as (Select LDACCT, LDDSC1, LDDSC5, LDTA, LDTYPT, LDPARC, 
COUNT(LDPARC) OVER (PARTITION BY LDPARC) 
as Liens
 FROM tbl_Loan_Legal_Descriptions)
Select A.ACCTNO, E.LDDSC1, E.LDDSC5, E.LDTA, E.LDTYPT, E.LDDSC5, E.LDDSC1, 
E.Liens, E.LDPARC, A.CALREP, A.SNAME 

From tbl_loan_master A
left outer join CTE E
On  A.ACCTNO = E.LDACCT

Where
E.Liens >= 1 and            
A.STATUS <> 2 and
A.QRYBAL > 0

Group By
A.ACCTNO, E.LDDSC5, E.LDTA, E.LDTYPT, E.LDPARC, A.SNAME, A.CALREP, E.LDTYPT, 
E.Liens, E.LDDSC1, E.LDDSC5

Order By
A.ACCTNO
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works,
A few things to note on using GROUP BY, only put things that you don't want to be duplicated
If its the count of *tbl_Loan_Legal_Descriptions* just put it the select count(1).

Comment: Thanks Grit - wish it did.  I have many accounts where it comes up with incorrect counts of LDPARC.  There's one LDACCT say it's 465 that has two LDPARCs 040038 and 040033. Rather than the query output showing the LDACCT once and a value of 2 Liens, it shows the LDACCT twice with each LDPARC having a Lien count of 1. Amazingly, it also has another LDACCT (the first on the output) that has a count of two Liens when there is only one LDPARC.  Long story short, the count isn't working and I'm not eliminating duplicate LDACCTs.

Comment: Forgot to note that all the Group Bys were required minus the duplicates (my bad)

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue with my query was that I shouldn't have used OVER(PARTITION BY and instead should have used DISTINCT as this provides for the correct counting of LDPARC.  I also had some LDPARC values that were blank so I had to account for those with the Where clause in the CTE (blanks caused massive counts).  Making the change to the count also forced me to use a Group By in the CTE. The final change was to the BAL field I was using in the last Where clause (unique for my data and not useful for anyone outside).  Here is the correctly working query.  Thanks Grit and anyone else stopping by.

```
;With CTE as
(Select LDACCT, LDDSC1, LDDSC5, LDTA, LDTYPT, LDPARC, 
COUNT(DISTINCT(LDPARC)) 
as Liens
FROM tbl_Loan_Legal_Descriptions
Where LDPARC <> ''                                      --NEW
Group By LDACCT, LDDSC1, LDDSC5, LDTA, LDTYPT, LDPARC  --NEW
)
Select A.ACCTNO, E.LDDSC1, E.LDDSC5, E.LDTA, E.LDTYPT, E.LDDSC5, E.LDDSC1, 
E.Liens, E.LDPARC, A.CALREP, A.SNAME 

From tbl_loan_master A
left outer join CTE E
On  A.ACCTNO = E.LDACCT

Where
E.Liens >= 1 and            
A.STATUS <> 2 and
A.QRYBAL > 0                                            --NEW

Group By
A.ACCTNO, E.LDDSC5, E.LDTA, E.LDTYPT, E.LDPARC, A.SNAME, A.CALREP, E.Liens, 
E.LDDSC1

Order By
A.ACCTNO
```